# Does a function declaration create an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Function constructors are able to create objects in javascript but 
I have a more basic question.

Declaring a plain function in Javascript using a "function declaration" such as

```
function Foo() 
{
  this.prop1 = 20;
  //some code
}
```

Does this create an object internally in javascript heap with pointer as abc and prop1 as 20?

Or is it that the objects are created only when the function constructor is called
like

```
var a = new Foo() //This definately creates a new object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, all functions are objects.

You can do things like this:

```
function foo() {
    return true;
}

foo.greeting = "hello";
foo.tone = "mean";
foo.talk = function() {
    alert(foo.greeting);
}

foo.talk();
```

A function object has all the same capabilities as a normal javascript object, but it can also do some additional things such as be used as a constructor and it has a few built-in properties.  See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) on Function objects for a description of the other properties/methods it has.

Comment: Given a variable how can we tell whether it is a function object or a normal object using javascript code?

Comment: @seahorse: With `typeof`. It will return `"function"` for functions.

Comment: You can also do `myFunction instanceof Function` or `myFunction.constructor == Function`

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration only creates *function object* `Foo`, but it does **not** call the function or create an instance of it.

An instance is only created when you actually call the function with `new` and until then, the property you assign to `this` does not exist anywhere.

It could also very well be that `Foo` is never called as a constructor function. Just by looking at a function, you cannot know for certain whether a function is used as a constructor function or not.

Comment: Whats the difference between a function object and a normal object in javascript?

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is an object. So internally, functions are objects too, but with special properties (they are callable). "Normal" objects are not callable.

Comment: It's important to know that while everything is an `object`, not everything is an `Object`. `true` is not an Object, while `new Boolean(true)` is.  Strings, booleans, and numbers will autobox to handle existing properties, but new properties assigned to primatives are immediately discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the execution line by line, adding line 8 for a better understanding:

```
/* 1 */ function Foo() 
/* 2 */ {
/* 3 */   this.prop1 = 20;
/* 4 */   //some code
/* 5 */ }
/* 6 */ 
/* 7 */ var a = new Foo()
/* 8 */ var b = Foo()
```

Line 1 executes, the heap now contains one element, a function object named `Foo`.  At this point, `Foo` hasn't executed.  Lines 2 through 5 aren't executed at this point but are used as the body of Foo.  Since `Foo` hasn't been called, line 3 hasn't been called on any object so nothing has a `prop1`.

Line 7 executes, the interpreter does several things:

1. It adds a new object to the heap.
2. It gives this object the prototype chain of `Foo`.  This does nothing special in the case of `Foo` since we haven't assigned anything to `Foo`'s prototype, but `Foo` inherits from `Object`, so the object now has methods like `hasOwnProperty` and `toString`.
3. The interpreter calls `Foo` passing the newly created object as `this`.
4. Line 3 gets executed, assigning 20 the property named `prop1`.  Whether this creates a new object in the physical heap or if it gets assigned to a primitive section of the object really depends on how the interpretter optimizes everything.  I'm sure V8 avoids adding an object to the heap.
5. The new object gets assigned to `a` in the variable scope of `a`.

So basically, creating a function adds the function loader to the heap (or possibly stack depending on scope and optimizations), and executing `new Foo` adds a new object to the stack.

*But what if we didn't use `new`?*

For fun, lets see the different behavior when we don't use `new`. When line 8 executes, since we aren't calling `new` we perform a normal function call and don't create a new object.  The following happens:

1. We call `Foo` on line one.  Since we aren't in strict mode, `this` is assigned to the global `window` object.
2. Line 3 executes, assigning `window.prop1 = 20`.
3. The function returns `undefined`.
4. `b` is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a little bit confusing because a function is both a normal function with no/default context, but paired up with `new` it creates a new object. So

```
function Foo() {
    this.prop1 = 20;
}

console.log( typeof(Foo) ); //-> 'function'
```

creates an object called Foo which is of type `function`. Now we can take our function objects and create new objects that will be added to the current stack:

```
var bar = new Foo();
console.log( typeof(bar) ); // -> 'object' with a pointer named prop1 to 20
```

Now we have 2 objects, `Foo` and `bar` which references an object that was created using Foo as a constructor with new. So `new` is basically magic and is one of the three ways of creating objects in Javascript. The three ways are:

```
var object = {}; // Creates an object using object literal notation
new Foo(); // Creates an object with built in 'new'
Object.create(null); // new ECMA5 notation that avoid using new
```